# How to separate negative numbers and positive numbers from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o

I want to separate negative numbers and positive numbers in an array.

For example, if my array has 10 values and they are {-8,7,3,-1,0,2,-2,4,-6,7}, I want the new modified array to be {-6,-2,-1,-8,7,3,0,2,4,7}.

I want to do this in O(n^2) and I have written a code as well. But I am not getting the right outputs. Where is my code wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Apples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomInteger=new Random();
        int[] a=new int[100];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            a[i]=randomInteger.nextInt((int)System.currentTimeMillis())%20 - 10;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<0)
            {
                int temp=a[i];
                for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
                {
                    a[j]=a[j-1];
                    j--;
                }
                a[0]=temp;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the rule to determine order of numbers, especially if these signs are the same? Reverse of input for negative numbers and same order as input for non-negative numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment quite well. I am just trying to take all the negative numbers and throw them towards the beginning of the array. That way by the end, I will have all my negative numbers at the start followed by positive numbers(including zero) towards the end.

Comment: remove  `j--;` line because you did it in for loop

Comment: @Jerry06 Thanks a lot. That was such a silly mistake. Apart from that, the code is perfectly fine right? Also how do I select your comment as the right answer? I am new to stackoverflow so I have no idea.

Comment: Throwing all the negative numbers one one side, and the positive numbers on the other side can be accomplished by a sorting algorithm.  Better yet, if the order does not matter within each group, just do a single iteration of the QuickSort or HeapSort algorithm with the pivot equal to 0.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 if you can live with an O(n) space complexity, you can define a new array of same size and loop through the first array and start filling the new array with negative numbers from left side of it and positive numbers from right side of it. This will yield an O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I already did that. I wanted a O(n^2) algorithm specifically. Thanks.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 Why do you want an O(n^2) algorithm when it can be done in O(n)?

Comment: @pjs Because it's part of the exercise in a textbook that I am working on. It's just for educational purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 Do you want the specific output given for your example, or is that meant to be illustrative that all the negatives end up on the left, all the positives on the right?  In other words, does the specific ordering matter?  Your example shows positive values retaining their order, negative values ending in the reverse of their initial order.

Comment: Actually order doesn't matter. Hence I went with whatever I could think of at that moment.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 The big O notation means that any complexity equal or lower the given one is valid. So any algorithm that performs O(n) also satisfies the O(n^2) condition. It would be different, if the constraint is Θ(n^2) which also sets the lower complexity limit.

Comment: @grek40 I do know that. I just wanted a longer algorithm and thanks to stackoverflow community, I am able to execute that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `j--` while you need only one, so remove either one of them.

```
for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
 {
     a[j]=a[j-1];
     // remove j--; from here
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You might consider the following as an alternative way of doing the partition of negatives/positives.  This is based on K&R's quicksort, but only makes one pass on the array:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Sweeper {   
   public static void printArray(int[] a) {
      for (int elt : a) {
         System.out.print(elt + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
      int tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
   }

   public static void partition(int[] a, int target) {
      int last = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
         if (a[i] < target && i != last) swap(a, i, last++);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random rng = new Random();
      int[] a = new int[20];
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         a[i] = rng.nextInt(20) - 10;
      }
      printArray(a);
      partition(a, 0);
      printArray(a);
   }
}
```

Comment: Not what is required, this will change the order of the elements as well, For example, If Input: -6 7 -10 7 -8 -2 2 -9 8 -2 3 6 -8 4 0 -7 -3 7 7 4, output will be -6 -10 -8 -2 -9 -2 -8 -7 -3 7 3 6 2 4 0 7 8 7 7 4, but the output should be : -6 -10 -8 -2 -9 -2 -8 -7 -3 7  7  2  8  3 6  4 0  7 7 4

Comment: @PyThon Order wasn't a stated requirement. Humans doing things by hand tend to do them sequentially, and that was my perception of his example.

Comment: @PyThon By the way, note that OP's example also alters the original order of the negative quantities.

Comment: I am sorry guys, if I was not clear in my question. The order did not really matter. When I was solving the example, I just went through what came to my mind at that moment. and @pjs Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 Thanks for the clarification.  In that case, this answer meets your criteria, since O(n) is in O(n^2).